# Problem remapping function buttons on Ubuntu 18.04 / i3 / xkb

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard-shortcuts, i3, xkb

I have been trying to remap my functions keys on my X1 Carbon 6th gen, since there's no Media Keys on the default keyboard.

Until now, I have remapped F8, F9 and F10 to respectively XF86AudioPrev, XF86AudioPlay and XF86AudioNext using the xkb config in */usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pc* and modified keycodes in */usr/share/X11/xkb/keycodes/evdev*. The new keybindings works, however, old key mappings is not removed thus the button have two actions.

This is how I did it:

I found the keycodes of F8, F9 and F10 (FN not toggled) using xev to respectively 245, 179, 246.
Then I went to /evdev and created shortcuts for F8,F9 and F10 like this:

```
<FN08> = 246;
<FN09> = 179;
<FN10> = 245;
```

And deleted the premade shortcuts for keycode 246,179 and 245 called I246 = 246 etc.

In symbols/pc, I added mappings for the keys F8-10:

```
key <FN08> {    [ XF86AudioPrev     ]   };
key <FN09> {    [ XF86AudioPlay     ]   };
key <FN10> {    [ XF86AudioNext     ]   };
```

I rebooted my system, and ran xmodmap -pke which gives me:

```
keycode 179 = XF86AudioPlay NoSymbol XF86AudioPlay
keycode 245 = XF86AudioNext NoSymbol XF86AudioNext
keycode 246 = XF86AudioPrev NoSymbol XF86AudioPrev
```

Okay, great! Using my F8, F9 and F10 keys, I can now control songs in spotify, etc. However, besides the F-keys executes XF86AudioSomething, they execute their old mappings as well. F8 for instance, toggles my Wifi (it was mapped to XF86WLAN before) besides executing XF86AudioPrev.

#### How do I remove old keybindings for my function keys? According to xmodmap, the F-keys isn't even bind to the old mappings.

- System: Ubuntu 18.04
- WM: i3
- PC: X1 Carbon 6th gen
- Keyboard layout: Danish (no dead keys)